# e(fx)clipse generated exe for javaFX project treated as virus by system antivirus

Tags: java, ant, javafx, javafx-8, efxclipse

I'm in process to create/bundle native wrapper for my javaFX project. The project is running in the IDE e(fx)lipse. Using the IDE's build script generate feature I have generated the Ant build which I'm then using to build the app from IDE/command line.

The problem is whenever the build is generating the exe wrapper, the system antibirus(Symantec) is detecting that as a virus and deleting that. This is happening for the simple **Hello World** projects also. I tried the signing using a generated key also but the problem remained.

It is not possible to disable my antivirus since I'm working in my office machine and will not get corporate approval to do that.

Anyone faced similar issue? or know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you/your team one of the first to be generating home-brew `.exe`s under this anti-virus software? If so, could be that the anti-virus was set up with something like a "detect generated `.exe` files and delete them" flag. Might be worth checking if it's a new version, update, etc.. Maybe also check building a new `.exe` file in a different program and see how Symantec handles it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem only existed if the ant build uses the JDK1.8.0_40 32bit version. Not sure what caused the error but I have tried with other versions like JDK1.8.0_5 32 bit, JDK1.8.0_25 32bit, JDK 1.8.0_45 32bit, JDK1.8.0_40 64bit and all of these versions worked flawless.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with JDK1.8.0_60 and NetBeans IDE.